# Changing the default font style and size of metro framework in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, metroframework

I'm using the MetroFramework v1.2.0.3. Is there a possibility to change the default font in Metro Framework? I think the default font style is "Segoe UI" and I want to change it to "Century Gothic". I'm searching about this problem but I don't see any solution. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: It's been inactive for 7 years.. your best shot is digging its source code.

Comment: https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/master/MetroFramework.Fonts/FontResolver.cs
This would help.

Comment: @LouisGo do you know where I can find the FontResolver.cs or I need to create it manually?. Thanks

Comment: Look at github repo, you have to make your own library of MetroFramework. I assume you're using it, but you have to check yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MetroFramework you can't se the font size directly. You have to basically edit the code in MetroFramework project and create a new size like "Extreme" or something and then define what that size is. I have done this in the past and its not very difficult. Just add the MetroFramework projects to your solution and trace how a MetroLabel gets initialized. That will be a good starting point.